# newbie python beautifulSoup extract articlebody from NewsArticle

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've the following XML portion:

```
<section class="article-body">
         <!-- <EdIndex> -->
         <div class="squared-inline-picture-offset no-mobile">
          <picture class="lazy square pull-left">
           <img height="" width="" alt="" src="" class="loaded">
           <noscript><img src="" width="" height="" alt="" /></noscript>
          </picture>
         </div>    
         <p>bla1 bla1 bla1</p>
         <p>bla2 bla2 bla2</p>
         <p>bla3 bla3 bla3</p>
         <!-- </EdIndex> -->
         <div class="adv no-mobile">
         </div>
   </section>
```

and I need to extract the "bla bla bla" part.
I tried with

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
  [...] 
 soup.findAll('section',{"class" : "article-body"})
```

with bad results:(

any hint?
Are there any quickly way to get article body from http://schema.org/NewsArticle using python and BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Can you expand on "*bad results*"?

Answer (score 0):

When you say ('section',{"class" : "article-body"}) you are asking for the articale-body class. This means its going to give you well... everything back....

What you want to do, is specify items in it. In this case, you can go down to 'p'
like this.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> p = soup.findAll('p')
>>> print(p)
[<p>bla1 bla1 bla1</p>, <p>bla2 bla2 bla2</p>, <p>bla3 bla3 bla3</p>]
>>> print(p[1].text)
bla2 bla2 bla2
```

Note: that you can only .text when its on the list item, not on the list it self.

Has you see, it finds all p elements then gives you a list of every element it found. This will select all p elements though, so if i wanted to select specifically this you'd do something like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
result = soup.find('section', {'class': 'article-body'})
results = result.findAll('p')
for p in results:
    print(p, p.text)
```

Output:

```
<p>bla1 bla1 bla1</p> bla1 bla1 bla1
<p>bla2 bla2 bla2</p> bla2 bla2 bla2
<p>bla3 bla3 bla3</p> bla3 bla3 bla3
```

So to get the raw text of the elements with headers what ever you want again. Just remember, find all gives you a list, find gives you the first element it falls on.

Edit: fixed some copy pasting errors.